# Setting a sound to fire in the background

Tags: avaudioplayer, ios5

I want my app to be able to fire a sound file or a series of sound files on a set timer countdown whilst the app is in the background. Has anyone done this and is so how is this achieved?

I don't want a local notification to be fired just the sound file(s).

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the backgrounding mode is set in the info.plist and then use AVAudioPlayer

## or

Use the system sound function (its an AudioToolbox function if I'm correct) without the backgrounding mode in the info.plist